# Error report - ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
CREATE TABLE DRIVER 
(
    Driver_Licence VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
    SSN            VARCHAR2(7),
    First_Name     VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL,
    Last_Name      VARCHAR2(7),
    Birth_Date     DATE DEFAULT '01/01/1900',
    Hire_Date      DATE,
    State_Name     CHAR(2),

    CONSTRAINT Driver_PK PRIMARY KEY (Driver_Licence),
    CONSTRAINT Driver_UC UNIQUE (SSN),
    CONSTRAINT Driver_CHK CHECK (Hire_Date > Birth_Date)
);

/*
Hire Date corresponds to the date the employee was first hired
*/
```

Trying to create a table in SQL but keep getting the error in the title

> ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column

Comment: You probably should make your Birth_Date and Hire_Date columns DATE data type not VARCHAR2. If you do make them VARCHAR2 then you need to make them long enough to hold the formatted values - and you'd better use a yyyy/mm/dd sort of format if you are going to do comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I changed the data types but I'm still getting the Error any idea why?

Comment: Use [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) `date '1900-01-01'` instead of `to_date` or string representation of the date with default implicit conversion

Comment: By the way, `char` is not a useful type in Oracle, so `char(2)` would be better as `varchar2(2)`. Also a lot of names are longer than 7 characters (mine, for example).

Comment: Please post the INSERT statement that failed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misplaced error
`ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column` for creating table, that error is for inserting statement.

For creating the table, you need to convert to date for default value of column "Birth_Date". I try to run this script on my env and running well.

```
CREATE TABLE DRIVER 
(
    Driver_Licence VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
    SSN            VARCHAR2(7),
    First_Name     VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL,
    Last_Name      VARCHAR2(7),
    Birth_Date     DATE DEFAULT TO_DATE('01/01/1900', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
    Hire_Date      DATE,
    State_Name     CHAR(2),

    CONSTRAINT Driver_PK PRIMARY KEY (Driver_Licence),
    CONSTRAINT Driver_UC UNIQUE (SSN),
    CONSTRAINT Driver_CHK CHECK (Hire_Date > Birth_Date)
);
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Exactly; ORA-01401 won't be raised with CREATE TABLE, but INSERT (which the OP didn't post).

Comment: All the VARCHAR2 field definitions seem a little short. SSN is always 9 digits long (11 if you include dashes); DL# is more than 8 characters in some jurisdictions; etc.

Comment: This helped a lot thank you. Again I'm very new to SQL and this my first time posting on stack overflow I appreciate your patience and understanding. Thanks again!